# Issue querying Athena with select having special characters

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Below is the select query I am trying:

```
SELECT * from test WHERE doc = '/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt';
```

This query returns zero results.

If I change the query using `like`, it works omitting the special chars `/-.`

```
SELECT * from test WHERE doc LIKE '%folder1%folder2%path%testfile%txt';
```

This works

How can I fix this query to use `eq` or `IN` operator, as I am interested to run a batch select?

Comment: Are you saying that the contents of the `doc` field is exactly the string you've shown (`/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt`)? Have you looked in the source file to verify that it is stored exactly that way? If you remove _any_ of the `%` from the second example, does it always return zero rows?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to show the row in the file that contains this value, and the `CREATE TABLE` definition (or at least the relevant parts)?

Answer (score 0):

To test your situation, I created a text file containing:

```
hello
there
/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt
this/that
here.there
```

I uploaded the file to a directory on S3, then created an external table in Athena:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE stack (doc string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("separatorChar" = ",", "escapeChar" = "\\") 
LOCATION 's3://my-bucket/my-folder/'
```

I then ran the command:

```
select * from stack WHERE doc = '/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt'
```

It returned:

```
1   /folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt
```

So, it worked for me. Therefore, your problem would either be a result of the contents of the file, or the way that the external table is defined (eg using a different Serde).

Comment: I realised, my field value includes double quote

select * from stack WHERE doc = '"/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt"'

My field value is "/folder1/folder2-path/testfile.txt"
that includes a double quote

Comment: Yes this is fixed, i created  new table specifying below format
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)